# connection of remote host database working on using ssh but unable to connect using laravel 5

Tags: database, laravel, ssh

I have a  laravel 5 project i want to connect multiple database connection for data handling method.

The db connection is must established the remote host db.
when i use

`ssh root@example.com`

it works,
when use laravel 5 it not working
what is the issue i am really stick with  problem , i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got results,

laravel db configuration as usual ,

in my server i was set remote ip address to my system ip address
now working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SSH to safely connect to remote DB, you should create [ssh tunnel](http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html):

```
ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p db
```

And then use it's port and host address in your .env configuration file:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'www.xxxxx.in',
            'port'      => '3307',
            'database'  => 'xxxx_xxx',
            ...
        ],
```

If you mean you just need to connect to remote DB (without SSH), you need to set up your .env file and allow connections from remote servers on the server where DB is.

```
mysql> CREATE DATABASE foo;
mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO bar@'202.54.10.20' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: via ssh connection working, how to establish connection via laravel

Comment: Please read second part of my post. You need to grant right for the user to allow remote connections and then edit Laravel .env file